# Alert on Input focus, which has no class or ID and is within a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, focus

How can I alert a message once the input is focused, of the following HTML code:

```
<div class="ss_datesel_inp_cont">
    <div class="ss_datesel_inp_right_corner"> </div>
    <input autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

This is what I tried but none works:

```
$(".ss_datesel_inp_cont:input").click(function() {
    alert("focused");
});

// or

$(".ss_datesel_inp_cont:input").focus(function() {
    alert("focused");
});

//or 

$(".ss_datesel_inp_cont").find("input").focus(function() {
    alert("focused");
});
```

Comment: Just wondering: shouldn't the input at least have a name? I don't think it's strictly required, but almost all implementations of form submissions use input names to populate the data being sent in the GET/POST. If you use a name, that gives another way to select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:input` selector will only work if the the given element is an input (also textarea, select, and others).  The `.ss_datesel` etc. class is not on the input, it's on the div.  You can simply use a descendant selector instead:

```
$(".ss_date_etc input").click(function() { alert('focused'); });
```

However, this will only work if click the input.  If you focus it by tabbing or automatically, the alert won't occur.  Problem is, if you use `.focus`, `alert()` steals the focus and then reapplies it in some browsers and you will be stuck in a focus loop.  Here's a simple solution:

```
$(".ss_date_etc input").focus(function () {
   if (!$(this).data('focused')) {
      $(this).data('focused', true);
      alert('focus!');
   }
});
```

Note that not all browsers will restore focus after an alert, even if you try to force them to.  You may want to use some alternative to `alert`, especially because that would be really annoying to users.

You can also update `.data('focused')` to `false` on blur so this happens over again.

Comment: Still none of these work. I appreciate your answer. I managed to add a class to it, and on click or focus still nothing happens. Since the input and div's are parsed from an API there's should be somewhere in the API to say on that input click/focus return false.

Comment: @jQuerybeast the obvious question is: are you including jQuery properly?  Other than that, are you sure that the classes in the html are matching those in the jquery code (notice that I changed some of the class names in my examples)

Comment: I am not new with jQuery. Everything works fine. Your code works find aswell and thank you. It just, what I'm trying to achieve doesn't work with this API. I tried every single solution. It's an entire web app and those classse and inputs are parsed. I managed to add a class on the input and still focus or click doesn't work.

Comment: @jQuerybeast is it possible that the html is added after the document has loaded/after this jQuery code is run?  Have you tried binding the events with `.delegate()`?

Answer (score 1):

You're going at it wrong with your jQuery selector.  This should work:

```
$(".ss_datesel_inp_cont input").focus(function() {
    alert("focused");
});
```

Also, your input is not set up properly...although "text" is the default input type, you should always specify the type on the input:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Interestingly enough, your third attempt seemed to work in my test.  Good luck.

Comment: well your attempt doesn't seem to work as you mentioned my 3rd attempt works that means there is something wrong with my code. The input and div's are generated through an API and that is the problem why my code aint working...